Siren library (Force update): TestFlight and production build must have same versions?
I am implementing a Force Update feature in my iOS application, and I am using Siren SPM for to fulfil this problem. Is Siren SPM has the limitation, that CFBundleShortVersionString must be follow the same series as the AppStore version series.
I have a series of TestFlight version (CFBundleShortVersionString), always greater than the Appstore version. Version against each TestFlight build show in table below
TestFlight (CFBundleShortVersionString)            |           AppStore versions
         3.0.5                          |                    1.0.6
         3.0.4                          |
         3.0.3                          |                    1.0.5
         3.0.2                          |                    1.0.4

So, while As far I know Siren SPM always compare CFBundleShortVersionString with AppStore version, which is never be valid in my case.
Questions:
1 - Is Siren SPM (https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren) really have this limitation? (scenario above): if yes
2 - How will I implement this scenario?
3 - Most of the solutions on internet compares CFBundleShortVersionString with Appstore version, so what is the good practice? The one that I am already implemented or the one that is AppStore version should be same as TestFlight version.
